# Pivoting pandas DataFrame -- AssertionError: Index length did not match values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a *pandas.DataFrame* that won't pivot the way I expect.  While `pivot_table` properly arranges everything, the fact that it uses aggregate functions to get there is off-putting.  In addition, `pivot_table` seems to return an unnecessarily complex object rather than a flat data frame.

Consider the following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['Jon']*3+['Amy']*2,
                   'lastname':['Cho']*3+['Frond']*2,
                   'vehicle':['bike', 'car', 'plane','bike','plane'],
                   'weight':[81.003]*3+[65.6886]*2,
                   'speed':[29.022, 95.1144, 302.952, 27.101, 344.2],})
df.set_index(['firstname','lastname','weight'])

print('------  Unnecessary pivot_table does averaging  ------')
print(pd.pivot_table(df, values='speed',
                         rows='firstname','lastname','weight'],
                         cols='vehicle'))

print('------ pivot method dies  ------')
print(df.pivot( index=['firstname','lastname','weight'],
                columns='vehicle',
                values='speed'))
```

The `pivot_table` results are

```
vehicle                       bike      car    plane
firstname lastname weight                           
Amy       Frond    65.6886  27.101      NaN  344.200
Jon       Cho      81.0030  29.022  95.1144  302.952
```

Is there a way to get `pivot` to give essentially the same output as the `pivot_table` command did (but hopefully flatter and neater)?  Failing that, how do I flatten the output of `pivot_table`?  What I want as output is something more like this:

```
firstname lastname weight     bike      car    plane                           
Amy       Frond    65.6886  27.101      NaN  344.200
Jon       Cho      81.0030  29.022  95.1144  302.952
```

Comment: What does the desired dataframe look like?

Comment: If you want a flat dataframe, just do ``.reset_index()`` on the result of pivot_table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want the aggregation of `pivot_table`, you indeed need the `pivot` function. However, `pivot` does not work with providing multiple index-columns (actually I don't know why). But, there is a similar function to pivot, [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), which works the same but based on the (multi) index instead of columns.

So to use this, you can first set the columns you want as index/column labels in the result as index:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['firstname','lastname','weight', 'vehicle'])
```

and then unstack on the last level (default), so on 'vehicle' (which become the column labels):

```
In [3]: df2.unstack()
Out[3]:
                             speed
vehicle                       bike      car    plane
firstname lastname weight
Amy       Frond    65.6886  27.101      NaN  344.200
Jon       Cho      81.0030  29.022  95.1144  302.952
```

And if you don't want the multi-index, you can 'flatten' the result with `reset_index`.
The only possible problem that you can have with this is that the columns also have two levels, so you can first remove the first level, and then reset the index to become a really flat dataframe:

```
In [17]: df3 = df2.unstack()

In [18]: df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel(0)

In [19]: df3.reset_index()
Out[19]:
vehicle firstname lastname   weight    bike      car    plane
0             Amy    Frond  65.6886  27.101      NaN  344.200
1             Jon      Cho  81.0030  29.022  95.1144  302.952
```

Comment: I'm still getting a MultiLevel for `df2.columns` though the index is now clean

Comment: Do you mean ``df3``? You tried the `df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel(0)`?

Comment: It doesn't quite work because the names needed are at different levels.  There's probably some pandic way to do it but I just went with a list comprehension and logical trigraph.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you need to first drop the level, and only then reset the index. Because otherwise you end up with the needed names at different levels.