# Unstacking a Pandas dataframe when one column has some NaN entries

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have a Pandas DataFrame for which I am pivoting some row entries into columns, using the `unstack()` method (as advised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727920/pivoting-pandas-dataframe-assertionerror-index-length-did-not-match-values)).  To do so, I `set_index` with the unpivoted columns, and then call call `unstack()` to get the dataframe I really want.

However, if some elements of the index are NaN, I get some annoying errors.  Sometimes I am told the index has duplicate entries (which is untrue) and other times I am told NaN cannot be converted to an integer.  Here is an example

```
import pandas
from numpy import nan

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'agent': {
                      17263: 'Hg',
                      17264: 'U',
                      17265: 'Pb',
                      17266: 'Sn',
                      17267: 'Ag',
                      17268: 'Hg'},
    'change': {
                      17263: nan,
                      17264: 0.0,
                      17265: 7.070e-06,
                      17266: 2.3614e-05,
                      17267: 0.0,
                      17268: -0.00015},
    'dosage': {
                      17263: nan,
                      17264: nan,
                      17265: nan,
                      17266: 0.0133,
                      17267: 0.0133,
                      17268: 0.0133},
    's_id': {
                      17263: 680585148,
                      17264: 680585148,
                      17265: 680585148,
                      17266: 680607017,
                      17267: 680607017,
                      17268: 680607017}}
            )
try:
    dupe = df.copy().set_index(['s_id','dosage','agent'])
    badDupe = dupe.unstack()
except Exception as e:
    print( 'Error with all data was: %s'%(e,) )
try:
    getnan = df.ix[17264:].copy().set_index(['s_id','dosage','agent'])
    badNan = getnan.unstack()
except Exception as e:
    print( 'Error dropping first entry was: %s'%(e,) )
df.dosage[:3]=42
willWork = df.copy().set_index(['s_id','dosage','agent'])
u = willWork.unstack()
print(u)
```

the output of which is

```
Error with all data was: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
Error dropping first entry was: cannot convert float NaN to integer

                   change                                 
agent                  Ag       Hg        Pb        Sn   U
s_id      dosage                                          
680585148 42.0000     NaN      NaN  0.000007       NaN   0
680607017 0.0133        0 -0.00015       NaN  0.000024 NaN
```

As you can see, if I set *dosage* to something other than NaN (here, 42) then the reshaping operation works fine.

What is the best way to get the reshaped dataframe I seek?  Should I put a sentinel value in for dosage and then substitute later?  That seems...inelegant.

Comment: I think this is a bug report rather than a question, you should post this as a github issue. Sentinal seems valid workaround for the moment.

Comment: I made the bug report...reshape is so magical I am never sure if the problem is me or a bug.  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4862

Answer (score 0):

Executed your code in pandas 0.16 version without `df.dosage[:3]=42`, it works:

```
In [1405]: u
Out[1405]: 
                 change                                 
agent                Ag       Hg        Pb        Sn   U
s_id      dosage                                        
680585148 NaN       NaN      NaN  0.000007       NaN   0
680607017 0.0133      0 -0.00015       NaN  0.000024 NaN
```